# How to protect cocos creator images ?

Tags: javascript, android, xcode, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocoscreator

Is there is any way that is helpful in encrypting or obfuscating the images that is used inside the cocos creator , I've tried to change it to base64 but struggled in returning back to png on loading time also , if there is any way to do it native inside Android Studio or Xcode that would be helpful ,,

note that the used language is Javascript

Thanks